# Solve Van der Pol equation by Padé approximation

Tags: approximation, nonlinear-optimization, approximation-theory

I want to solve the Van der Pol equation:

$$f''+ \mu \, (f^2-1)f'+f=0, \quad f = f(t),$$

by Padé approximation.

I know the solution should be the combination of $\sin{t}$ and multiplied by $\mu$, then I apply Padé approximation equating to a fraction with $2$ power series and find $p$ and $q$.

However, I just do not how to work out my original $f$.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Could you find a power series solution first then construct the desired Padé approximant from that?